# Change layout by changing class/ID in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to change the layout of a page(2 column, one column, multiple column), by just changing the class or ID of body element, there are certain restriction, as i felt while doing it. has anyone implemented it before? any best practices??

Comment: It should be fine, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the body class or id with its parent element...
For example, you have to style ids like "wrap1" and "wrap2"...
So you can implement it likewise...

```
body#wrap1 .container { // Your Style }
body#wrap2 .container { // Your Style }
```

For division by columns simply use floating css for it if the layout is not complex enough...